# CU or ALU? What communicates with memory?

Tags: memory, cpu, bus, alu

I have different books saying different things. Are the address bus and data bus connected to the CU or the ALU? The control bus connects to the CU right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The CU (Control Unit) is responsible for all data transport to and from the ALU. The ALU doesn't see buses, it sees two N-bit wide inputs, and ditto output. The CU must make sure that both inputs of the ALU are loaded (latches) with the required data. When the ALU has performed the operation the CU will route the output via internal (and possibly external) databus to register or RAM.

Comment: Yes but does the ALU send and receive data directly to and from memory under the control of the CU or does the CU have to act as an intermediate between the ALU and memory?

Comment: The ALU has no idea how the data gets there or where it goes to, it can only perform the logic operation. It's not aware of buses, ports or latches. That's all CU business. The CU routes the data to the ALU, and back to memory.

Comment: Right, so the buses are attached to the CU, which then forwards the data to the ALU and then forwards the results back to the buses.

Comment: No.  The data doesn't go through the CU, because data and control paths are separate.

Comment: So the address bus and data bus go to the ALU? It's just the control lines that go to the CU?

Comment: @mtanti - Yes. There will be latches to hold the content of input A of the ALU while the CU uses the bus to fetch the content for input B. When the ALU operation is complete the CU will allow the output on the databus to be latched in a register of a RAM location.

Comment: Then the Memory Address Register and Memory Data Register are in the ALU?

Comment: @mtanti - No. Like I said the ALU doesn't care about where data comes from and where it goes to. It only sees two numbers which it has to add, for example. Memory Address Register and Memory Data Register are part of the Instruction Fetch logic, which is controlled by the CU. The ALU **ONLY** sees its two inputs and 1 output, that's all.

Comment: Then where are those registers located? If they are in the CU then that means that the CU receives the data from the memory and then passes it to the ALU and vice versa.

Comment: @mtanti - I wouldn't exactly say "inside the CU" although it's all on the same chip of course. But there are latches to hold this data, and these are controlled by the CU. The CU basically is driven by the clock, and generates all kinds of signals mainly to enable data and addresses on their buses, and latches to freeze data before fetching the next.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it is a philosophical question and not a pragmatic architectural question.  This is a question that might be asked in a University class but not asked by a real CPU designer.

I've designed several CPU's, in VHDL.  These ranged from simple bit-slice DSPs, several 8-bit MCU clones, and a full 32-bit MIPS R3000 clone.  In every case the line separating CU from ALU was very blurred.  In fact, in many cases the ALU was not a distinct unit and was more "spread throughout the logic".

My philosophical answer to your question is that the address and data busses are connected to the ALU, but the various paths are controlled by the CU.  But this answer is of zero use to anyone outside of a university classroom.

Comment: You're right, this is an academic question not a practical one. I'm only asking it here because there's no better stackexchange site for it.